# is it possible to have currentValue = previousValue in ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, typescript, onchange, angular-lifecycle-hooks, ngonchanges

As per my understanding, the `ngOnChanges` hook is only invoked when an input property undergoes a change. Therefore, it seems logical to say that within the ngOnChanges hook, changes.property?.currentValue and changes.property?.previousValue are always different. In other words, will this code make sense:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   if (changes.steps?.currentValue !== changes.steps?.previousValue) {
        // do something only if value is really changed
    }
 }
```

I am seeking clarification to ensure that there isn't a specific scenario or edge case where these values might unexpectedly be the same.

Comment: if `changes.step` is undefined you will not get inside the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` is triggered when any input property *changes*, so for any single property that's being monitored, the `currentValue` will *always* be different than `previousValue` because those values would be mapped **only if the change actually exists**. Thus, the posted condition will **always** return true. Keep in mind, though, that there might be a `SimpleChanges` object returned by the hook, but changes *might not* be of the property you're checking for, i.e. `changes.steps`, so yeah be sure to have the `?` there as you do now.